# Bundling controllers in a module gives undefined in angularjs 1.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to bundle all of my controllers in same module say app.core but it results in undefined.

app.js

```
angular.module('app',['ui.router','app.routes','app.core']);
```

app.core.js

```
angular.module('app.core', []);
```

sidebar.ctrl.js

```
 angular.module('app.core',['ui.router','ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('SidebarController',function($scope,$uibModal){
 $scope.login=function(){
    $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl:'./partials/login/login.modal.tpl.html',
        size:'sm',
        controller:'LoginController'
    });
}});
```

login.ctrl.js

```
angular.module('app.core',['ui.router','ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('LoginController',function($scope){
$scope.closeLoginModal=function(){
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
}});
```

index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="partials/sidebars/sidebar.ctrl.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="partials/login/login.ctrl.js"></script>
```

When I run with above sequence of loading js files it gives Argument 'SidebarController' is not a function got undefined but when I comment login.ctrl.js script it gives no error but when opening login modal results in 'LoginController' is not a function got undefined.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead :

```
angular.module('app',['ui.router','ui.bootstrap', 'app.routes','app.core']);

angular.module('app.core', ['app']);

angular.module('app.core')
.controller('LoginController',function($scope){
$scope.closeLoginModal=function(){
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
}});
```

and try this order :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="partials/sidebars/sidebar.ctrl.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="partials/login/login.ctrl.js"></script>
```